# Converting and finding values

Tags: c#

I need help finding a value and values between two numbers, 0~274 and if the value is between these values it will allow my text on one of my forms to be black. If the text is 275~300 the text will be red.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Lent = richTextBox1.TextLength.ToString();
    l6.Text = Lent + "/300";
    if (Lent == "275")
    {
        l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else if (Lent == "274")
    {
        l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else if (Lent == "0")
    {
        l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

`l6` is my `label6` which displays the text length from the `richTextBox`, for example `"0/300"`. I've tried to find values between but failed and I really need some help!

Comment: Why are you setting ForeColor = Color.Red; for all of the conditions?

Comment: i made a small mistake while typing and failed to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep the length as a number, that way you can actually compare it properly with other numbers:

```
int length = richTextBox1.TextLength;
l6.Text = length + "/300";

// when the length is 0 or higher than 275
if (length == 0 || length > 275)
{
    // make the text red
    l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    // otherwise keep it black
    l6.ForeColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use integer comparison for range.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textLength = richTextBox1.TextLength;
        l6.Text = @"{textLength}/300";

        // Add ranges in condition and set color.
        if (textLength == 0 || textLength <= 274)
        {
            l6.ForeColor = Color.Black; //Whatever color
        }
        else if (textLength > 275)
        {
            l6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Alternate and more readable solution.

```
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textLength = richTextBox1.TextLength;
        l6.Text = @"{textLength}/300";
        l6.ForeColor = (textLength >= 275) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
    }
```

Comment: Your alternate solution does something completely different.

Comment: Based on the OP's question, for text length above 275, text needs to be red otherwise black.

Comment: @pokeYou know, the question along with example is not clearly stating the desired behavior. The idea which i was trying to convey was to use length as int and use whatever color based on condition.